# .bat script opens 2 webpages instead of one

Tags: batch-file

I have this .bat script that runs once every couple of hours. It's supposed to close any firefox process that is running and after 5 second, open a webpage.

This is the batch script:

```
cls
cscript CloseBrowser.vbs
ping -n 1 -w 5000 1.1>null
start www.google.it
```

And here is CloseBrowser.vbs:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'firefox.exe'") 

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

Instead of opening a single page, from the second time it was launched, it opens two identical pages.

Comment: Firefox is most likely remembering the last page that was opened and is opening it again.  Most browsers have that functionality built in.

Comment: The resume last session option is already unselected.

Comment: You could use WMIC instead of launching a VBS. `WMIC Process Where "Name='firefox.exe'" Call Terminate 2>Nul`. Then use `Timeout` instead of `Ping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, with the addition of specifically opening the URL in Firefox, regardless of the default browser.

```bat
@WMIC Process Where "Name='firefox.exe'" Call Terminate 2>Nul
@Timeout 5 >Nul
@Start Firefox www.google.it
```

You could alternatively stipulate to open the URL in a new window:

```bat
@Start Firefox -new-window www.google.it
```

Command line options can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options#Browser).